# Sympy gets stuck with certain equations

Tags: sympy

I encountered a very strange problem with sympy (1.3). For example, if I use the following statement to solve this particular equation, it has no response until timeout:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Eq, symbols

x = symbols('x')    
solve([Eq(x + 3, 3*x)], {x})
```

However, if I changed the equation a little bit, it works fine.

```
solve([Eq(x, 3*x)], {x})
```

It also works fine if I use other format, such as removing the [ ]:

```
solve(Eq(x + 3, 3*x), {x})
```

I know there are different ways to format input, but the first one is what I used in the code, and I have no idea why it causes a problem.

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15415) in version 1.3. It has already been fixed in [master branch](https://github.com/sympy/sympy) which you may want to pull.

Comment: "Please note that there is another function called `solve` which can also be used to solve equations. The syntax is `solve(equations, variables)` However, it is recommended to use `solveset` instead." - Sympy docs https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html